# "Не то(,) чтобы очень" — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Все время путаюсь: нужна ли запятая в выражении "не то(,) чтобы очень..."? А то я раньше ставил много лишних запятых)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, запятая в устойчивом сочетании *не то чтобы очень* не нужна.